# I can't connect to wifi network after spoofing my mac address

Tags: wireless

I'm trying to connect to my own network but spoof my mac address: I can spoof my mac address fine, but when I try to connect to my wifi network, it won't let me connect.
And no my network doesn't have any sort of mac filtering.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, try to deactivate network-manager and activate it again. That did it for me.

After spoofing your mac, then run:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```